# Как передать параметры из функции внутри функции

Tags: javascript

```
 function example() {

    return function test(a, b) {
      return a+b;
   } 
  }
```

Скажите пожалуйста, как мне передать параметры а и b в example? Формат ниже не работает

```
function example(a, b) {

        return function test(a, b) {
          return a+b;
       } 
      }
```

Comment: вы функцию вернули. чтобы результат сложения получить надо ее потом еще и вызвать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function example(a, b) {
  return function() {
    return a + b;
  }
}

var t = example(2, 3);
console.log(t());
```

Comment: спасибо, но чуть-чуть не то, у меня функция test уже создана в другом месте и в ней хранится a и b и я из этой функции хочу получить параметры в функцию example

Comment: @quires Из "этой" функции нельзя получить параметры в функцию `example`. Функция `example` давно выполнилась.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю, что человек хочет ... просто за компанию

```js
const example = (() => {
  let [__a, __b] = [void 0, void 0];
  return (function (_a = __a, _b = __b) {
    return function (a = _a, b = _b) {
      [__a, __b] = [a, b]
      return a + b;
    }
  })
})()


var t = example(1, 2)
console.log(t())       // 3 !!!
console.log(t(3, 4))   // 7
var ttt = example()
// как и t(3, 4)
console.log(ttt())     // 7
console.log(ttt(4, 5)) // 9
// !!! как и в самом начале
console.log(t())       // 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно работать с глобальной видимостью.

Создайте в начале скрипта две var переменные. Тогда вы сможете внутри функций менять их значения и обрабатывать (без необходимости явно передавать).

```js
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
/* задаем глобальные переменные a,b */
function example() { 
console.log('переменная а = '+ a + ', Переменная б = ' + b);
}
example(); // запускаем функцию example
function changeVar(){
/* Зададим новые значения переменных внутри другой функции */
a = 3;
b = 'приветик';
}
changeVar(); // выполняем функцию, меняем значения переменных
example(); // ещё раз выполняем первую функцию с новыми значениями
```